# Obtain auth token using email instead of username

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to obtain auth token using email instead of username, i have changed serialized to accept just email but i think that i have something wrong.

```
class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for user authentication object"""

    email_or_username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(style = {'input_type' : 'password' }, trim_whitespace = False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """Validate and authentiate the user"""

        email_or_username = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request = self.context.get('request'), username = email, password = password)

        if not user:
            msg = _('Unable to authenticate with provided credentials.')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msd, code='authorization')

        attrs['user'] = user

        return attrs
```

And the View

```
class LoginViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """Check email and password and returns an auth token."""

    serializer_class = serializers.AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES

    def create(self, request):
        """Use the ObtainAuthToken APIview to validate and create a token."""

        return ObtainAuthToken().post(request)
```

when i make a test

```
def test_create_token_for_user(self):
    """Test that a token is created"""

    parametrs = {'email' : 'test@noah-lc.com','email' : 'test@noah-lc.com', 'name' : 'test', 'password' : 'testPASS@123'}
    create_user(**parametrs)
    res = self.client.post(TOKEN_URL, parametrs)
    print(res.data)
    self.assertIn('token', res.data)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I got this error

> AssertionError: 'token' not found in {'username': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}

Model of own user

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

And Setting

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.UserProfile'
```

Comment: Are you using any package?

Comment: please add code of `settings.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRF's `ObtainAuthToken` uses its [AuthTokenSerializer](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.0/rest_framework/authtoken/serializers.py) which expects a username not an email. So if you want to use an email, I would advice you create your own `ObtainAuthToken` view or even better off put the logic of `ObtainAuthToken` directly into your `LoginViewSet` as it seems to serve the same purpose. You can them create a custom `AuthTokenSerializer` which accepts emails instead of username or both and use with it

Comment: that's what i wanted to make, but i'm using DefaultRouter i found a problem here

Comment: Don't use `ObtainAuthToken().post(request)` because it uses it's own serializer as I already mentioned. Instead copy the logic from `ObtainAuthToken.post` method and add it directly to your `LoginViewSet`'s `create` method

Comment: Yes that's the solution i will have other problem in DefaultRouter.

Comment: @NoahLc You can post the problem separately as it is not related to this one

Comment: Yes, but i think that i'm going to use path instead of DefaultRouter

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you have an app named users, then define a new User model here,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

The important part is USERNAME_FIELD, that set email instead of username

then in settings.py add below line

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```